# How to use expression negation in ANTLR grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have below to implement in ANTLR grammar.

```
INPUT → EXPR ;
EXPR → if EXPR then EXPR else EXPR
         | { EXPR (; EXPR)* }
         | ! EXPR
         | id := EXPR
```

I have done for 'expr' , but getting error while writing for !expr.

```
input   : expr SEMICOLON;

expr    :   IF expr THEN expr ELSE expr 
|   ID ASSIGN expr  
    |   OBRACE expr ( SEMICOLON expr )* CBRACE
    |   !expr

    ;
```

This line is giving error -  ( !expr).How can I write the negation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `!` in `! EXPR` is probably the literal exclamation mark. So add it as a lexer rule:

```
expr
 : IF expr THEN expr ELSE expr 
 | ID ASSIGN expr  
 | OBRACE expr ( SEMICOLON expr )* CBRACE
 | NOT expr
 ;

...

NOT : '!';
```